# Заполнение списка python

Tags: python, append

Есть список, как мне пополнить его, чтобы данные вывелись так:

```
[{"value": 1},{"value2" : 2}]
```

вот такой список у меня, я хочу дополнить его, чтобы данные заполнились вот так:

```
[{"value": 1, "new_value": 3},{"value2": 2, "new3": 4}]
```

Т.е есть я делаю apps.append({}),то новые данные записываются в конец, а мне надо, чтобы с самого начала записывались

Comment: OrderedDict  использовать пробовали?

Comment: У Вас как бы словари в списке.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич `OrderedDict` вроде бы уже не нужен, с какой-то версии питона словари сохраняют порядок ключей.

Comment: @CrazyElf вроде как не обещают сохранить это свойство в будущих версиях. Типа оно "случайно получилось" ?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Ну я на самом деле не знаю, и непонятно, важно ли это в данной задаче вообще.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Сначала оно случайно получилось. С 3.7 эту особенность официально закрепили в спецификациях. "Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order." "Еhe insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec." Так что вряд ли будут выпиливать это обратно.

Comment: @GrAnd спасибо за важное дополнение. Оставлю ссылки здесь: 
 https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html  https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#what-s-new-in-python-3-7

Answer (score 2):

У вас два словаря внутри списка. Чтобы записать что-то в словари нужно просто присвоить им значения по ключам:

```
lst = [{"value": 1},{"value2": 2}]
lst[0]["new_value"] = 3
lst[1]["new3"] = 4
print(lst)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'value': 1, 'new_value': 3}, {'value2': 2, 'new3': 4}]
```